# IndexError: tuple index out of range . Odoo 14

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

In my code , I got this error :

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

When printing vals['partner_ids'] , I got : [(4, 3)]
Here is my code , what's wrong please?

```
class CalendarEvent(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'calendar.event'

    present_ids = fields.Many2many('res.partner', 'calendar_event_present_ids', 'calendar_id', 'present_id', string='Presents')
    minutes = fields.Html(string='Minutes')

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if vals.get('partner_ids', False):
            _logger.info("%s", vals['partner_ids'])
            vals.update({'present_ids': [(6, 0, vals.get('partner_ids')[0][2])]})
        return super(CalendarEvent, self).create(vals)
```

Comment: Tuple indexes start at 0, so if your tuple only has 2 elements, the only valid positive indexes are 0 and 1. Using 2 gives you an error

Comment: how can I solve it please ? when trying with[0][1],I got this error:  TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable@Ceres

Comment: try printing `vals.get('partner_ids')`

Comment: I got : [(4, 3)] , @Ceres

Comment: You can check the possible values of `partner_ids` at [x2many values filling](https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/py/x2many.html#odoo-14-0)

Comment: @Kenly, vals.update({'present_ids': [(6, 0, vals.get('partner_ids'))]}) , I got error : psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "present_id" is of type integer but expression is of type record
LINE 1: ..._present_ids (calendar_id, present_id) VALUES (9, (4, 3)) ON...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: When using `[(6, _, ids)]`, ``ids`` should be a list of integers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list_data = vals.get('partner_ids')[0][2]
blank_list = [ls for ls in list_data] # you'll get the list
```

or you can use loop to create list

```
blank_list = []
for l in list_data:
    blank_list.append(l)
# then use [(6, _, ids)]
vals.update({'present_ids': [(6, 0, blank_list)]})
```